# Couchbase get buckets and views

Tags: couchbase

I just started Couchbase.

I would like to find a way to query couchbase to get all buckets like

```
Select * from tab;
USE <DB NAME>
```

and retrieve all **views** as they are faster to pull the data from N1Q1.

Comment: Views are not categorically faster than N1QL, and there are rebalancing issues to consider that N1QL can be immune to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of buckets with N1QL: `SELECT r.name FROM system:keyspaces r;`

There is no way that I know of to query for a list views with N1QL itself.

You can use the REST API:

To get a list of design docs (which contain views): check out `GET /pools/default/buckets/<bucket.name>/ddocs`

For more details, check out the documentation:

- [Getting Views Information](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/rest-api/rest-views-get.html)
- [System Keyspaces](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/security/roles.html#system-keyspaces-tables)

Answer (score 3):

```
select name from system:keyspaces;
```

Gives all the buckets. For view definitions you need to use @Matthew Groves suggestions.